# Android: attribute type is required in declaration of "CDATA"

Tags: android, dtd, cdata

***First error solved, please read my comment on Daniel Haley's answer.***

I pretty new to Android developing and used changed the size of a picture in a layout XML file.

Since then im always getting this error:

> Error:(1, 151) The attribute type is required in the declaration of attribute "CDATA" for element "LinearLayoutxmlns:android".

And I have no idea, what it's telling me... Google only seems to give me very few results all with similar code.

Here is the content of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE LinearLayout [<!ELEMENT LinearLayout (ImageView|TextView)*><!ATTLIST LinearLayoutxmlns:android CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_width CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_height CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:background CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:gravity CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:orientation CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingBottom CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingLeft CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingRight CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingTop CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:theme CDATA #REQUIRED><!ELEMENT ImageView (#PCDATA)><!ATTLIST ImageViewandroid:id CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_width CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_height CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:paddingTop CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:src CDATA #REQUIRED><!ELEMENT TextView (#PCDATA)><!ATTLIST TextViewandroid:layout_width CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_height CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_gravity CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_marginLeft CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:layout_marginTop CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:text CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:textSize CDATA #REQUIREDandroid:textStyle CDATA #REQUIRED>]>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/pyroappappicon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the attlist declarations, your attribute names aren't separated by spaces.

For example `LinearLayoutxmlns:android` (from the error message) should be `LinearLayout xmlns:android`.

Another example is `#REQUIREDandroid:layout_width` should be `#REQUIRED android:layout_width`.

Here's a version with the attlist declarations fixed.

It validates now but since I don't know anything about android development I don't know what changes you made and if they're going to work the way you intended.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE LinearLayout [
<!ELEMENT LinearLayout (ImageView|TextView)*>
<!ATTLIST LinearLayout
    xmlns:android CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:layout_width CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:layout_height CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:background CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:gravity CDATA #REQUIRED 
    android:orientation CDATA #REQUIRED 
    android:paddingBottom CDATA #REQUIRED 
    android:paddingLeft CDATA #REQUIRED 
    android:paddingRight CDATA #REQUIRED 
    android:paddingTop CDATA #REQUIRED 
    android:theme CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT ImageView (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST ImageView
    android:id CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:layout_width CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:layout_height CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:paddingTop CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:src CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT TextView (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST TextView
    android:layout_width CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:layout_height CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:layout_gravity CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:layout_marginLeft CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:layout_marginTop CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:text CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:textSize CDATA #REQUIRED
    android:textStyle CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/pyroappappicon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's another version with the doctype declaration all on one line like the original:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE LinearLayout [<!ELEMENT LinearLayout (ImageView|TextView)*><!ATTLIST LinearLayout xmlns:android CDATA #REQUIRED android:layout_width CDATA #REQUIRED android:layout_height CDATA #REQUIRED android:background CDATA #REQUIRED android:gravity CDATA #REQUIRED android:orientation CDATA #REQUIRED android:paddingBottom CDATA #REQUIRED android:paddingLeft CDATA #REQUIRED android:paddingRight CDATA #REQUIRED android:paddingTop CDATA #REQUIRED android:theme CDATA #REQUIRED><!ELEMENT ImageView (#PCDATA)><!ATTLIST ImageView android:id CDATA #REQUIRED android:layout_width CDATA #REQUIRED android:layout_height CDATA #REQUIRED android:paddingTop CDATA #REQUIRED android:src CDATA #REQUIRED><!ELEMENT TextView (#PCDATA)><!ATTLIST TextView android:layout_width CDATA #REQUIRED android:layout_height CDATA #REQUIRED android:layout_gravity CDATA #REQUIRED android:layout_marginLeft CDATA #REQUIRED android:layout_marginTop CDATA #REQUIRED android:text CDATA #REQUIRED android:textSize CDATA #REQUIRED android:textStyle CDATA #REQUIRED>]>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/pyroappappicon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, first of all, thank you! Why did Android Studio generate it like this, if it's incorrect?

Also: i used the version with all in one line, now i get the following error: "Error:(13, 56) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'LinearLayout'."
Do you know, what this means?